# Stuck at "Installation Type" screen while installing

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I'm installing Ubuntu from a USB, onto a computer running Windows 7. Everything seems to run perfectly, until I get to the "Installation Type" screen.

Essentially, I am not getting a choice for my install. I am taken directly to the partitioning screen. It has options like "New Partition Table...", "Add...", "Change..." etcetera, as well as a drop-down menu "Device for boot loader installation:".

Anyhow, nothing responds on this screen (but the computer does not seem frozen). From the Ubuntu website screenshots, this should be pretty straightforward!

What do I need to do to get Ubuntu installed?

Answer (score 3):

My 13.10 install got stuck at a previous screen, asking if i wanted to replace windows, do something else, etc. The 'continue' button wouldn't enable.  I clicked back, then next, and it cleared the problem.  you probably already tried that?

Comment: I am not even getting that choice... somehow I need to start partitioning the HDD, so I assume I'm getting straight to the "Do something else option", although nothing else than the Install button works. 

When I press it, I get a message stating that there is no defined place for the root of the system, which isn't surprising considering that I can't make any of that steps' operations work. I'm installing from USB, tried two different flash drives but still : not working.

I'm still looking for an answer deep down in the documentation and this forum!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your disk is readable.  In my case **AHCI** was not set in the bios.

You can boot the usb in *Try Ubuntu* mode, then run *terminal*.  Next try `fdisk -1` or `parted -l`.

If your harddrive isn't in the list then make sure its bios settings are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not have a bootguard, e.g., Symantec PGP, as it does not allow dual boot and you may end up losing your data.